# Send a vector using the R httr GET function's `query` parameter

Tags: r, httr, fastapi

For sending a vector of values, say an array `list_a = c(1,2,3)` FastAPI will accept a URL of the form:

`https://wherever.com/endpoint?list_a=1&list_a=2&list_a=3`

However using library [httr's query parameter](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html#the-request) to the GET function, you have to pass a list of key/value pairs. This means you can't have the same field twice because R will not accept a list with duplicate keys obviously.

So how do I do this? I could build the URL myself, but the problem with that is some of my parameters have double quotes (`"`) in them which don't seem to be parsed properly if I put them directly into the url. The `query` parameter does seem to handle these properly however.

Is there any way to get the `query` parameter of httr's `GET` to create multiple identical field names?

Alternatively how do I encode a pre-created URL that has double quotes in it like the one below so that it does not cause FastAPI to give at HTTP error?

`"query/Crude/?actual_table_name=live.crude&report_id=xxxxxxx&fields=IMO&where={\"Barrels\":{\"gt\":1},\"conjunction\":\"\"}&where={\"Load Date\":{\"gt\":\"'2000-01-01'\"},\"conjunction\":\"\"}&offset=1e+05&limit=10000"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easiest to build the query string yourself, then you could use `URLencode` on the result:

```r
url <- "query/Crude/?actual_table_name=live.crude&report_id=xxxxxxx&fields=IMO&where={\"Barrels\":{\"gt\":1},\"conjunction\":\"\"}&where={\"Load Date\":{\"gt\":\"'2000-01-01'\"},\"conjunction\":\"\"}&offset=1e+05&limit=10000"
```

```
URLencode(url)
#> [1] "query/Crude/?actual_table_name=live.crude&report_id=xxxxxxx&fields=IMO&where=%7B%22Barrels%22:%7B%22gt%22:1%7D,%22conjunction%22:%22%22%7D&where=%7B%22Load%20Date%22:%7B%22gt%22:%22'2000-01-01'%22%7D,%22conjunction%22:%22%22%7D&offset=1e+05&limit=10000"
```